# Can we auto-expand an HTML 'details' when a hyperlink points to it?

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink

I am creating a page with language information.  Since it is extremely long, I collapse each language with details/summary tags and have them in alphabetic sections with each initial letter also a collapsed details.  Currently, each language is coded like

```
  <details>
    <summary id="am"><b>am — Amharic</b></summary>
    <p><a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/GBV-Amharic.jpg"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/GBV-Amharic-150.jpg"/></a>About 22 million native speakers, … [more info]</p><br clear="all"/>
  </details>
```

If I put a link elsewhere like `http://domain.TLD/path/#am`, I'd like to take the user to that page, scroll to that section, and expand the details.  If that's possible, do I have the wrong syntax for one or both sides?  It is **not** working now—nothing expands and it goes to the top of the page as if the # were not there.  But the address field shows the full URI of the link, #id included.

"`path/`" is interpreted by Wordpress and/or a Wordpress-generated `.htaccess`, so perhaps that somehow prevents it working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct syntax for directing a user to an element with the id "am."

You can check the URL the browser used to display the page with jQuery. For your example if a link sent a user to http://domain.TLD/path/#am the following code would trigger if the browser contained "path/#am" as part of the URL.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("path/#am")){
       /* do something to the element in jQuery -- likely apply a class.
       */
}
```

There are many animation and scrolling libraries related to jQuery as well.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps a little (I think) but it wouldn't be practical to check the URI for 184 different IDs in order to apply 184 different actions.  And I don't know what the action should be.  Seems to me that linking to an ID should cause the details that ID is in to expand, but it doesn't.  And it seems even more odd that it jumps to the top of the page even if the unexpanded detail with that id is below the fold.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe can hold the IDs in an array and iterate through.Should be the same action though for each -- maybe as simple as display: none ->block or something.  [This](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) details how to prevent the jumping to the top of the page behavior.

Comment: It's not jumping to the top of the page.  It's a link elsewhere that should jump to the line on the languages page that has that ID.  But it is going to the top of the page.  Perhaps having the details collapsed is making it act as if the ID doesn't exist.  And it can't be the same action for each if each one must expand a _different_ details section.